# Count how many columns are bigger than 0

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has some numeric columns. I need to count how many have values that are greater than 0, and to add it as a new column.

For example:
The current table is:

```
A | B | C | D | E |
2 | 4 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

The output would be:

```
A | B | C | D | E | "New column"
2 | 4 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 3
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1
```

Comment: I have just edited your topic title to make it more explicit. Just saying bigger than "0" doesn't help much. I think itshould be, "greater than value zero".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the brute force method:

```
select t.*,
       ((case when a > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when b > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when c > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when d > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when e > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as NewColumn
from currenttable t;
```

If you actually want a new column in the table, then you should do:

- alter the table to add the new column
- run an update statement similar to the above `select`
- consider a trigger to keep the value up-to-date

EDIT:

Alex's comment is worth mentioning.  In the more recent versions of Oracle, you can add a virtual column which would do this calculation as part of the table definition itself.  Virtual columns are definitely a better way to solve this problem than adding a new non-virtual column to the table.

Comment: Or add it as a virtual column (assuming 11g or later).

Comment: Thanks guys. Gordon's answer is good for me for that moment. Many thanks!

Comment: Since it is a computed column, I would go with Alex's siggestion of virtual column. It will reduce the maintenance too.